# CakePHP html helper imgage links

Tags: cakephp, html-helper

In Cake, we can add url in image() like this:
`$this->Html->image('image src...', array('url' => 'some address...');`
and output is:
 `<a href="some address..."><img src="image src..." /></a>`.

How to add class and others attributes to `a` tag?

Comment: You are better off using link and image functions as soon as you need more thwn that function alone gives you.

Comment: Okey, thanks for reply, I use link() with image();

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
echo $this->Html->link(
    $this->Html->image($imageSrc, array(
        'class'=>'class_of_image',
        'height' => '50',
        'width' => '100',
        'alt' => 'awesome close-up of me eating pizza'
    )),
    array(
        'controller' => 'your_controller',
        'action' => 'the_action'
    ),
    array(
        'class' => 'class_of_anchor',
        'escape' => false //to allow the image tag within the link
    )
);
```

Feel free to make any/all parts of this into a single line - but for StackOverflow reasons, it's easier to read like this.